# Weird Python import errors

Tags: python, python-import, amazon-emr

I'm having this really weird error where I'm getting import errors in a Python shell launched from a home directory of an AWS EMR whereas the same packages are getting imported fine when I `cd` into another directory and launch the Python shell there.

The EMR has Python 2.7 installed. Please let me know what additional information I can provide. This issue is driving me crazy!

```
$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 18 2019, 18:38:44)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import smtplib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "email.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
ImportError: No module named mime.multipart
>>> os.path.realpath('./')
'/home/abc123'
>>>
```

```
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp
[temp]$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 18 2019, 18:38:44)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import smtplib
>>> os.path.realpath('./')
'/home/abc12/temp'
```

Comment: Is there a file named ``email.py`` in the first (home) directory? Or a folder named ``email``? If yes, then this can influence the import behaviour, due to python's lookup mechanics (app root takes precedence over other imports).

Comment: Unbelievable! Dumb guy me created a test script to test the email functionality and named it `email.py`. Thank you! Do you want to change your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a file named `email.py` in the first (home) directory? Or a folder named `email`? If yes, then this can influence the import behaviour, due to python's lookup mechanics (app root takes precedence over other imports).

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path): (emphasis mine)

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - **The directory containing the input script** (or the current directory
>     when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.